# Prevent execution of updateSelectizeInput until needed

Tags: shiny

I have a number of selectizeInputs spread across multiple tab panels (called as modules). My problem is that the corresponding updateSelectizeInput (at server side) are executed at startup which causes a large delay. I would like for them to run when the UI element is shown, as is the case for everything else (as far as I can tell). Any hints? Thanks!

Comment: Have a look e.g. into `isolate()` or `req()`,...

Comment: But they don't take any inputs.


`updateSelectizeInput(session, "geneid", choices = someExpensiveFunction(), selected = character(0),
    server = TRUE`

Comment: No one? Is there really no other way than to wrap it in `isolate` and listen for clicks on the tabs? What is it that makes `updateSelectizeInput` different compared to, say, a plot or table that is generated when the corresponding tab is opened.